# I want to assign an image file to an image node inside an existing node group

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I'm trying to do something very simple, but cannot figure out what I'm missing. *I can do this fine when not accessing a node group.* The file 'image.png' exists. The material 'my_mat' has a node group 'my_group'.

```
def assign_image_to_node_group_node
    temp_folder = bpy.app.tempdir
    filepath = temp_folder + 'image.png'
    image = bpy.data.images.get(filepath )

    mat = bpy.data.materials["my_mat"]
    group = mat.node_tree.nodes.get("my_group") #QUITS HERE
```

I get  `KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "my_mat" not found'`

I also have tried: `group = mat.node_groups["my_group"]`

Comment: The material does not appear to have a node named p_mat. If p_mat is the name of the group (not the node in your material) you can access it directly without going through the material with `bpy.data.node_groups["p_mat"]`.

Comment: Would expect a key error in line above addressing `foo[key]` as opposed to `foo.get(key)` which will be `None` if it does not exist, and will not (as written) throw a keyerror.  The error complains about a key "p_mat".  Please clarify.

Comment: My mistake, the error would say "my_mat"
Still, even if I try ``` img_node = bpy.data.node_groups["my_group"] ``` it still throws the error. (how do use markdown here to designate a code block?)

Comment: Hence it is the line `bpy.data.materials["my_mat"]` throwing the key error , are you 100% sure you have a material named "my_mat" ?

Comment: Yes, definitely sure.

Comment: since I can't help with the python:  in a comment the markdown for `code` is to use the back-tick character as a delimiter.  Click "Help" when you're entering a comment to learn more.

Comment: Can you share a blend file showing the problem?  Even without the actual image texture it might be worth a look.

Comment: Sorry: Not convinced. Could you try typing this in python console `D.materials.get("my_mat") is None` and report whether it is True or False?

Comment: yes, I'll share a file. one sec. Thanks for the help w/markdown

Comment: `bpy.data.materials.get("p_mat") is None` returns False (I'm using p_mat and not my_mat)

Comment: Sigh. This is going full circle. Have you tried then `mat = bpy.data.materials["p_mat"]` ?  It is this line throwing a key error, not the next.  Using get avoids keyerrors, instead check for none type result.

Comment: Here's a very simple file which shows the issue. I just want to add an image to the Image Texture 'my_texture_node' in the node group 'my_group' in the material 'my_mat'

https://filedn.com/lLMW4jXsJqxXkRYjd1UCoKL/aaTrash/test.blend

Check out the script workspace

Comment: Mr. bat, yes, `mat = bpy.data.materials["p_mat"]` works fine. The trouble is trying to target a node inside a group inside that material. Please see the file.

Comment: Yes, the new file I sent I changed to my_mat so to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The node tree of a group node is in `bpy.data.node_groups`**

In your blend.

```
>>> D.node_groups['NodeGroup']
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']

>>> D.materials['my_mat'].node_tree.nodes['my_group'].node_tree
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']
```

Load the image from a file path. It is named after the filename "image.png" not the whole path. using `Image.get(filepath)` probably wont work as expected and return `None`.

```
temp_folder = bpy.app.tempdir
filepath = temp_folder + 'image.png'
image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath )


>>> ng = D.materials['my_mat'].node_tree.nodes['my_group'].node_tree
>>> ng
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup']

>>> tex = ng.nodes.get('my_texture_node')
>>> tex
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup'].nodes["my_texture_node"]

>>> tex.image is None
True

>>> tex.image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)
```

Re your method, if you know it's a node group would address by node group name, instead of finding group node in a material. If do use group node in a material it's `node_tree` is a pointer to `bpy.data.node_groups["Foo"]` any way.

```
def assign_image_to_nodegroup_node(ng_name, node_name, img):
    ng = bpy.data.node_groups.get(ng_name)
    if not ng:
        return # or throw error.. print message       
    node = ng.nodes.get(node_name)
    if hasattr(node, "image"):
        node.image = img
```

Comment: OK, so I copied your code as you have it, and replaced the vars and I ran this from the script window in the test file I sent you:
`import bpy


temp_folder = bpy.app.tempdir
filepath = 'C:/test.png'
image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath )

ng = bpy.data.node_groups.get("my_group")
node = ng.nodes.get("my_texture_node")
node.image = image`

and I get a line 9 error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'` 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a link to an image showing the code a bit better: https://filedn.com/lLMW4jXsJqxXkRYjd1UCoKL/aaTrash/ber.png

Comment: OK, I moved up a bit in your code and then tried this, and it worked!
`node = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup'].nodes["my_texture_node"]

node.image = image`
( not sure how to add returns in comments )
Thanks a bunch :-)

Comment: I need to add one more comment to this thread. It turns out I was using the Name property of the node group, which is different from the the actual field inside the node. Once I applied the correct name in the field in the node group, everything worked.